# Terms and conditions of applicability of `AttachThreadInput`

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

This is a simple modification of a win32 initial code - generated from base template:

```
if (!InitInstance(hInstance,true)
{
    return false;
}

std::thread{ [hInstance,main_thread= GetCurrentThreadId()] {
    MSG msg{};

    if (!InitInstance(hInstance,true)
    {
        return;
    }

    auto const current_thread{ GetCurrentThreadId() };
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32APP));

    if (!AttachThreadInput(main_thread, current_thread, true))
        return;
    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    AttachThreadInput(main_thread, current_thread, false);
} }.join();
```

Two windows are created and shown. But obviously, messages sent to the window created in main thread are not processed. What is missing? I couldn't find anything in tones of msdn docs and lots of forum posts. All I can find in forums is lots of complains about `SetFocus` and modal dialogs - which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Why are you trying to run two UI threads? Why are you attaching the input processing mechanism of the threads together?

Comment: Calling `AttachThreadInput` is rarely necessary. When it is necessary, you already know what it does. You don't go calling it and then asking what it does. Since you are here's the answer: [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043).

Comment: Messages for the main window are not processed because the main thread isn't processing messages. AttachThreadInput is called AttachThreadInput because it attaches input state. It's not "AttachThreadMessageProcessing".

Comment: In what way and what exactly does it attach? I need to understand exacly and specifically what the function does; because obviously it does not do lots things but only one. The link provided, does not answer my question. What does `AttachedTreadInput` do? What is the input the name implies to be attaching? I want a single thread to process message queues for objects created in different threads.

Comment: I don't know what `AttachTreadInput` does, either. The article, though, talks about `AttachThreadInput`, and it assumes that the reader have a broad understanding of Windows' asynchronous input model. You probably just got yourself into a situation, where being a master of the rules is essential. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) The solution is easy: Don't get yourself into that situation.

Comment: @IInspectable  maybe I need a clue to the path that leads to mastering the rules. But again that article belongs to inter-process hacks; while I am asking about a clearer view of intera-process domain. My basic question boils down to what the function does if the per thread message queues are supposed opaque to other threads?

Comment: @RaymondChen That is exactly the point. What is `AttachThreadInput`? What it isn`t makes an infinite list.

Comment: The article I posted explicitly talks about cross-thread hierarchies. The issues involved aren't unique to cross-process scenarios.

Comment: Like it says in the function name: It synchronizes input. The docs say "Keyboard and mouse events received by both threads are processed in the order they were received." If the user clicks in one window, presses a key, and then clicks in another window, and presses a second key, then the second window will not be given the second key event until the first window finishes processing the first key event. Apps rarely need to do this. It is very much a niche scenario. (Doing so makes the app *less* responsive, since the second window is stuck if the first window is hung.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I see now. I was interested in message queues. I was just digging the wrong land but that led to another discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I had to go back and focus on the exact wording of the original dock. The term **Input** refers to **HID**. My confusion was due to the need for existence of message queues for both threads. So on the event of an input, different messages (pseudo) simultaneously get sent to both threads. Both threads will observe HID events; their perception of evets will be different, due different sequences recieved messages.

Thanks everyone for the hints.